# Как добавить представление к контроллеру?

Tags: c#, .net, rest

Пишу rest сервис для бронирования рабочих мест. Создал новый контроллер

```
public class JobReservController : ApiController
{
    List<JobPlace> jobPlace = new List<JobPlace>();
    public JobReservController()
    {
        jobPlace.Add(new JobPlace { _id = 1, _description = "Место 1", _duration = 3, _startTime = DateTime.Now, _floor = 14, _person="Иванов" });
        jobPlace.Add(new JobPlace { _id = 2, _description = "Место 2", _duration = 8, _startTime = DateTime.Now, _floor = 15, _person="Петров" });
        jobPlace.Add(new JobPlace { _id = 3, _description = "Место 3", _duration = 5, _startTime = DateTime.Now, _floor = 15,_person ="Сидоров" });
        jobPlace.Add(new JobPlace { _id = 4, _description = "Место 4", _duration = 5, _startTime = DateTime.Now, _floor = 15, _person="Пупкин" });
    }
    // GET: api/JobReserv
    public List<JobPlace> Get()
    {
        return jobPlace;
    }

    // GET: api/JobReserv/5
    public JobPlace Get(int id)
    {
        return jobPlace.Where(x=> x._id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    // POST: api/JobReserv
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT: api/JobReserv/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE: api/JobReserv/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

Хотел бы по ссылке из браузера `..../api/JobReserv` получить `html`(в виде кнопочек) со свободными или занятыми местами. Знаю что надо добавить представление(View) к этому контроллеру но не знаю как. Только знакомлюсь с этой технологией. Наведите на мысль в какую сторону копать.

Comment: [Use Razor Pages, MVC, and Web API in a Single ASP.NET Core Application](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/e6557104-d06a-418c-a1a9-b8ce248f60b1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй создай чистый проект с .Net MVC. Он покажет тебе взаимодействие Controller -> View.

Controllers/HomeController.cs

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            HomeModel model = new HomeModel("World")           
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Views/Home/Index.cshtml

```
@model HomeModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome @Model.Name</h1>
</div>
```